# Multiple Line Graph Labels - D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, label, linegraph

I am trying to replicate the [Multi-Series Line Chart example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955) but I am unable to get the labels to show up at the end of the line or at all for that matter. The code is basically all the same as the example but a few words changed. The dataset is of county population and is formatted the same as in the example, earliest date at the top of the list and most recent date at the bottom of the list.

Anyone see anything I'm missing??

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.population); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("historicalpopulationTest.csv", function(error, data) {
  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "date"; }));

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  });

  var counties = color.domain().map(function(name) {
    return {
      name: name,
      values: data.map(function(d) {
        return {date: d.date, population: +d[name]};
      })
    };
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));

  y.domain([
    d3.min(counties, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.population; }); }),
    d3.max(counties, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.population; }); })
  ]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
     .append("text")
      .attr("x", width)
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Year");

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Population");

  var county = svg.selectAll(".county")
      .data(counties)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "county");

  county.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

  county.append("text")
      .datum(function(d) { return {name: d.name, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.population) + ")"; })
      .attr("x", width)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

});
```

Graph looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is in the following code

```
county.append("text")
  .datum(function(d) { return {name: d.name, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.population) + ")"; })
  .attr("x", width)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

I haven't run your code, but it looks like you are translating the text to the end of the line and then moving the x position an additional 'width' number of pixels.

Try changing `.attr("x", width)` to .`attr("x", 3)`

Comment: Thank you! I thought I had changed my code back to .attr("x", 3)but I hadn't. That solved it.